# Bluetooth headset on Windows 10: is it possible using mic and stereo audio at the same time (Sony WH-1000XM4)?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, headset

I recently bought the Sony WH-1000XM4 and they sound really good, but whenever I try to use the mic, the stereo sound mutes itself - only using the low quality hands free sound profile is an option. The headphones are connected via Bluetooth to my Windows 10 PC (Bluetooth 5.0 adapter).

Googling and trying to solve this problem lead me to make this post because after reading many conflicting answers it's unclear to me if what I want is even possible.

[This 4-year old article says it's simply a limitation of Bluetooth - but then says Bluetooth 5.0 might fix it.](https://www.howtogeek.com/354321/why-bluetooth-headsets-are-terrible-on-windows-pcs/) So my question would be: has it?

[Then there's this even older post which had the same question I have.](https://superuser.com/questions/930251/possible-to-use-bluetooth-headset-in-stereo-mode-with-mic) The top answer is that it is not possible without aptX-capable headphones and even then it's not a guaranteed. Well, the XM4 don't support aptX and instead have LDAC, which apparently is not supported by Windows.

Aside from this I found lots of more recent and conflicting answers, some claiming it is impossible to do with Bluetooth, others offering help and instructions how to fix it (which I have tried unsuccessfully).

So I guess what I'm asking boils down to two questions:

1. General question: Is it possible to have high quality audio and use your mic at the same time with a Bluetooth headset on Windows 10?
2. If the answer to #1 is not a universal "no", then what are the requirements for this to work? What do I have to look for (e.g. support of a certain codec) to determine if I have to return my XM4 and look for another pair of headphones?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest reading through this tread. [What's the difference between stereo and hands free?](https://superuser.com/questions/1088942/whats-the-difference-between-stereo-and-hands-free)

I had the same problem and it seems there's no real solution other than using the lower quality audio or using an external mic

Comment: Welcome to SU. Please see the [guidelines on answering](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [Help center](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer). You should provide the context of the link in your answer; link-only answers like this will be [deleted](https://superuser.com/help/deleted-answers). I'd suggest taking the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and checking at least the Asking and Answering -sections in the Help center to learn how these sites work. Also reviewing some of the existing questions with accepted answers is helpful.